# Write a Python program to print the following sequence of numbers (N to be entered by user): X + X^3/3! + X^5/5!... Upto the Nth Term

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, sequence, python-3.8

The problem i am having with this question is that the code i have written is showing a logical error. Here is the code i have written:

```
x = int(input("Please enter the base number: "))
n = int(input("Please enter the number of terms: "))
s = 0
factorial = 1
for i in range(1,n+1,2):
    factorial = factorial*i
    s = (x**i) / factorial
    #using f string to format the numbers to a fixed number of decimal places
    print(f"{s:.6f}", end='+')
```

I used the for loop to only show odd values of index, because that is the requirement in the question. My output is coming as follows:

```
Please enter the base number: 2
Please enter the number of terms: 4
2.000000+2.666667+
```

We don't have to actually find the sum, only display all the individual addends separated by a plus sign. What changes should i make within the code to get the required results?

My required output would look something like this:

```
Please enter the base number: 2
Please enter the number of terms: 4
2.000000+1.333333+0.266666+0.025396
```

Comment: What's the expected output for this input?

Comment: I guess that it is : the number of required terms are not getting printed, but only half of them

Comment: the factorial calculation is also wrong since your loop skips a term

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change to
`for i in range(1,2*(n)+1,2):`

from

`for i in range(1,n+1,2):`

Now, the output is:

```
Please enter the base number: 2
Please enter the number of terms: 4
2.000000+2.666667+2.133333+1.219048+
```

Also, the method of calculating `factorial` is wrong as it skips half of the terms, when you jump `i` from 1 to 3 to 5, so that `2, 4, 6..` are getting missed.
So, you can do:

```
if i > 1:
    factorial = factorial*i*(i-1)
elif i == 1:
    factorial*i
```

So, the final code would be:

```
x = int(input("Please enter the base number: "))
n = int(input("Please enter the number of terms: "))
s = 0
factorial = 1
for i in range(1,2*n+1,2):
    if i > 1:
        factorial = factorial*i*(i-1)
    elif i == 1:
        factorial*i
    s = (x**i) / factorial
    #using f string to format the numbers to a fixed number of decimal places
    print(f"{s:.6f}", end='+')
```

Answer (score 0):

Factorial is in the loop but the loop does i=1,3,5 and not i=1,2,3,4,5, that's might be a problem. If the "number of terms" : "2.000000+2.666667" is two so in the loop your range avec to be until n*2 and not n but careful because the factory will be changed.